# Unable to access to calendar holidays

Tags: calendar, google-apis-explorer

I have a simple java client to access to different google calendars.
It works fine trying to access to every calendar but the holidays.

For instance:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/miId/events works fine.

but

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/es.spain#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the calendar parameter:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/es.spain%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events
```